# unistd.h - compilation failed

Tags: visual-studio-2015, flex-lexer

I use Flex with VS 2015 and Windows 10. I just can not compile programs, getting the following error:

```
cannot open source file "unistd.h"  
Cannot open include file: 'unistd.h': No such file or directory 

Here is the code section OF lex.yy.c file which this error relates to:

#ifndef YY_NO_UNISTD_H
/* Special case for "unistd.h", since it is non-ANSI. We include it way
 * down here because we want the user's section 1 to have been scanned first.
 * The user has a chance to override it with an option.
 */
#include <unistd.h>
#endif
```

I have tried all the suggestion from same posts for help.

When I add the `%option nounistd` , this error disappears, but then I get two other errors:

```
Warning C4013   'isatty' undefined; assuming extern returning int   
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C4996   'fileno': The POSIX name for this item is deprecated. Instead, use the ISO C and C++ conformant name: _fileno. See online help for details.
```

I am just helpless.

Comment: Add an `#include <io.h>` to your flex input file for isatty. If you want to remove the warnings, you can also `#define fileno _fileno` and isatty to _isatty.

Comment: @Hitobat however, when I add #define isatty _isatty, I still the get the same error related to isatty

Comment: @Hitobat it doesnt work